# CSS: Add pipe on all div except last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to add pipe between links except after the last . My html is rendered in the following way , html is rendered with same class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:last-of-type {
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I need to add Pipe but after last link no pipe should be displayed . How can i do it for this case .

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/myg5mgL4/)

P.S. : This can be done easily when we have different links with different class . In my case links are dynamic and after last link no pipe should be displayed

Comment: try like this https://jsfiddle.net/myg5mgL4/1/

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this selector `.sample:not(:last-of-type)`, which will target all but the last item.

*Do note, when combining a class name with `last-of-type`, it will target any element type not being the last (if there is more than 1) having the given class.*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myg5mgL4/3/)  (added the *pipe* to the `div` so it won't pick up the color from the `p`)

```
.sample:not(:last-of-type) > div::after {
  content: ' | ';
}
```

---

Another option is `last-child`, `.sample:not(:last-child)`, which also will target all but the last.

*Do note, when using `last-child`, it means the last no matter class or element type, so if you have another element coming after the last `sample`, that will count as the last, and here is [a fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/myg5mgL4/5/) showing how this rule will fail in cases like that.*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myg5mgL4/4/)  (added the *pipe* to the `div` so it won't pick up the color from the `p`)

```
.sample:not(:last-child) > div::after {
  content: ' | ';
}
```

---

A third option is to use the immediate sibling selecor `+`, which target all sibling elements with the given class but the first.

```css
p:last-of-type {
    background: #ff0000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sample + .sample > div::before {
  content: ' | ';
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
 <div >
  <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
 <div >
  <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
 <div >
  <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my bad, just didnt saw your answer, it works fine, as long as there is only one div in .sample :) and dont forget IE8 does not support "::before" :)

Comment: @Neil IE8 support the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:before), and if to remove the `>` it would add a pipe to all div, if there were more than one, which means the answer relate to the given question, not what other might have

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

'Add a pipe before each link - only if it comes after another one'

```
.sample + .sample .para:before {
  content: "|";
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.sample + .sample .para:before {
  content: "|";
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div >
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this.

```css
.sample:last-child div {
   border: none;
}
.sample div {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div>
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div>
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sample" style="display:inline-block">
    <div>
        <p class="para">link1</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works, but i think you should remove the "last of type" part, for other people than OP searching for a clear answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to add this CSS rule:

```
.sample:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9c8szuc5/2/

Comment: hmm, I actually meant `last-of-type`, which does work... (changed that in my answer)

Comment: @Neil It does work with `last-child`, though most code testers adds element of their own in the end of the body, hence `last-child` stops work ... with a wrapper it work: https://jsfiddle.net/9c8szuc5/3/

Comment: now it works, i was just pointing a typo :), and thats the way i would do it too